# When $\Bbb Z_n$ is a domain or field, i.e. $ab \equiv 0 \Rightarrow a\equiv 0\,$ or $\,b\equiv 0\pmod{\! n}$ and forms of zero divisors.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

Suppose $\,ab \equiv 0 \pmod n\,$ and $\,0<a,b < n \ $ (so $n\mid ab,\ n\nmid a,b)$

Does it follow that either $a | n$ or $b | n$?

For this question is this a suitable answer: No it doesn't. $3$ and $4$ are both less than $6$. $$3 \times 4 \equiv 0 \pmod {6}$$

but $4 \not \mid 6.\,$  However, can such $\,a,b\,$ always be found?

Comment: You should not change your question this way, because it deprecates all previously given answers!!!

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is an integral domain iff $n$ is prime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your answer is incorrect.

**Either/Or** means it's sufficient that one of them abides the condition.

And in the specific example at hand, one of them indeed does, as $3|6$.

A proper counterexample would be $8\times9\equiv0\pmod{12}$.

---

$$[a=8,b=9,n=12]\implies[ab\equiv0\pmod{n}]\wedge[a<n]\wedge[b<n]\wedge[a\not|n]\wedge[b\not|n]$$

Comment: So, then how can I prove this? Can you help me?

Comment: @Megan: See the counterexample I just added.

Comment: Okay so I can write "No it doesn't. 8 and 9 are less than 12. 8×9≡0(mod12) but $8 \mid 12$ and $9 \mid 12$." Is that fine?

Comment: @Megan: Write $[a=8,b=9,n=12]\implies[ab\equiv0\pmod{n}]\wedge[a\not|n]\wedge[b\not|n]$.

Comment: @Megan: And please revert your question to the original version, otherwise all answers given here prior to your change (including this one) become somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: Okay I have changed it. And what does the symobol ^ mean exactly

Comment: @Megan: $\wedge$ means Logical-AND.

Comment: Is there something else that I can write, that is understandable for me, since I am new to this?

Comment: @Megan: Yes, you can write `AND`.

Comment: Ok and what about the other symbol before the n

Comment: @Megan: What symbol before the $n$???

Comment: the one at the end

Comment: does it mean does not divide?

Comment: @Megan: Yes, but... you've used it in your own question. Did you do that without knowing what it meant?

Comment: No I did. The symbol looked different in yours, thats why.

Answer (score 1):

$$10 \dot \ 12 \equiv 0 \mod 15$$

But neither $10|15 $, nor $12 |15$.

**Edit:**

If you consider $n$ prime, then $\gcd(n , a) =1$ for $a = 1, \ldots, n-1$. Let any $\overline{a} \in \mathbb Z_n - \{\overline{0}\}$ then there exist integers $b$ and $t$ such that

$$ab + nt =1 \Rightarrow \overline{ab + nt} = \overline{1} \Rightarrow \overline{a}\ \ \overline{b} + \underbrace{\overline{n}}_{=\  0}\ \ \overline{t} = \overline{1} \Rightarrow \overline{a}\overline{b} = \overline{1}$$

then $\overline{a}$ is invertible, it follows that $\mathbb Z_n$ is a field (every element is invertible), therefore a integral domain.

Comment: Okay, so can you help me prove it then. I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Sure, prove what?

Comment: Disregard my solution, I'll change it above.

Comment: The proof consists in showing a counterexample.

Comment: Yes, but if it does follow, then I have to give a proof.

Comment: You need $n$ prime.

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: If $n$ is prime then $Z_n$ is a field, and a field is an integral domain, therefore it holds.

Comment: Feel free to ask.

Comment: I am not quite familiar with all the notations you used there. I was looking for a more simpler answer like the one above.

Comment: That doesn't answer the case where if follows.

Comment: Can you perhaps give a simplified answer that I could understand as I am just starting this course?

Comment: Do you know what a field is? What about an integral domain?

Comment: No, I don't know/

Comment: Well, in order to answer your question is very important to know what those algebraic structures are. I don't know where did you see this question, but for now you may only get the second part. And you should probably change your question.

Answer (score 1):

Zero divisors in $\Bbb Z_n$ needn't be factors of $\,n,\,$ e.g. $\,6\mid 4\cdot 9\,$ but $\,4,9\nmid 6.\,$ Yes, *we can* force it true by choosing smaller factors of each factor, as follows. $ $ Suppose that $\!\bmod n\!:\ ab\equiv 0\,$ for $\,a,b\not\equiv 0.\ $ Let $\,k =\,$ additive order of $\,b.\,$ Then $\,a\cdot b\equiv 0\equiv n\cdot b\,\Rightarrow\, k\mid a,n\,\Rightarrow\,k\mid (a,n),\,$ so $\,(a,n)b\equiv 0.\,$ Similarly we deduce $\,(a,n)(b,n) \equiv 0,\,$ where, indeed, $\,(a,n)\mid n,\ (b,n)\mid n;\,$ e.g. applying this to the above  we get $\, 6\mid 4\cdot 9\,\Rightarrow\, 6\mid(4,6)(9,6) = 2\cdot 3,\,$ where $\,2,3\mid 6$.

Thus if $\,n\,$ fails Euclid's Lemma (Prime Divisor Property) $\,n\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\,n\mid a\,$ or $\,n\mid b,\,$  the above yields a *constructive* proof that  $\,n\,$ is composite, by constructing a *proper* factor $\,(a,n)\,$ of $\,n.\,$ Indeed, $\,(a,n)\ne n\,$ else $\,n\mid a,\,$ and $\,(a,n)\ne \color{$c00}1\,$ else $\,n\mid (a,n)(b,n)=(b,n)\,\Rightarrow\,n\mid b.\,$
[For example,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4604/242) given any polynomial $\,f(x)\in\Bbb Z_n[x]\,$ with more roots than its degree, we can quickly compute a nontrivial factor of $\,n\,$ via a $\rm\,gcd.\,$ Said failure of Eclid's Lemma is sometimes described with the language: $\,ab\,$ is a **witness that $\,n\,$ is composite**, i.e. $\,n\mid ab,\ n\nmid a,b$.

Said algebraically: not prime $\,\Rightarrow\,$ reducible or, contrapositively, irreducible $\,\Rightarrow\,$ prime. Since the converse always holds, we conclude: $\,\Bbb Z/n\,$ is a domain $\iff n\,$ is prime $\iff n\,$ is irreducible.

This idea is sometimes used in integer factorization algorithms to deduce a factor of $\,n\,$ from a "nontrivial" factor of a multiple of $\,n.$

The above constructive proof also [generalizes to certain ideals,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/168094/242) namely

**Theorem** $ $  If ideal $I\ne 1$  satisfies: ideal $\,J \supset I \Rightarrow J\,|\,I\,$ then  $I$ not prime $\Rightarrow I\,$ reducible (*properly*).

**Proof** $\ $  $I$ not prime  $\Rightarrow$ exists $a,b \not\in I$  and  $ab \in I.$
$\ A := (I,a)\supset I \Rightarrow A|I,$ say $I = AB;$ wlog we may assume $b \in B$
since  $A(B,b) = AB\,$ via $Ab = (I,a)b \subset I = AB.$ The factors $A,B$
are *proper:* $A = (I,a),\, a \not\in I;\,\  B \supset (I,b),\, b \not\in I.\quad$  **QED**

Comment: But I thought that Barak's example was when it "doesn't follow"

Comment: @Megan The point is that every counterexample can be transformed into an example as described above.

Comment: So what you are basically saying is that every example that does not follow can be forced into saying that it does follow?

Comment: Can you also explain each step that you took. I am having trouble seeing how this is true for my problem.

Comment: @Megan Look at the example. Although the property does not hold for $\,12\mid 8\cdot 9\,$ we can mechanically transform it to $\,12\mid 4\cdot 3\,$ where it does hold, which is often a useful way of finding factors of $\,n.\,$

Comment: But doesnt 12 divide 72?

Comment: Wait nevermind I get what you are saying. You made it to 4 and 3 so now we can have 12 divides 4 and 12 divides 3. Right?

Comment: @Megan Yes, that's the point, we can always transform it that way by taking gcds as shown. This idea often proves useful, esp. when viewed in the language of "orders" of elements as in the proof. The structure at the heart of the matter will become clearer if you study (cyclic) groups (but you needn't know that to understand the above).

Comment: @Megan I added some remarks about how it relates to the property of being an (integral) domain.