# Show that $(3, 1+\sqrt{-5}) \neq \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that it is *not* possible to find "integers" $x, y$ of this kind which satisfy the equation $3x-(1+\sqrt{-5})y=1$, even though $3$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$ are "primes", and therefore their greatest common divisor is 1.

My effort: I let  $x$ be $a+b\sqrt{-5}$ and $y$ be $c+d\sqrt{-5}$ and then substituted this into $3x-(1+\sqrt{-5})y$.

I ended up with this being $(3a-c+5d)+\sqrt{-5}(3b-d-c)$, and for this to be $1$, I postulated that $(3a-c+5d)$ must equal $1$ and $\sqrt{-5}(3b-d-c)$ must equal $0$.

I end up with two equations with four unknowns, giving infinite solutions. What have I done wrong? Also, what is the significance of this question in terms of learning the difference between the natural numbers and "integers" of this kind?

Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for (regular) _integer_ values of $a,b,c,d$; you're right that there are infinite solutions over the reals (or rationals), but that doesn't guarantee that any of them have all four values integral. As a hint: what does your equation that $\sqrt{-5}(3b-d-c)=0$ say about $d+c\bmod 3$? What does the first equation say about $5d-c\bmod 3$? Can you see a way to relate these two statements and derive a contradiction?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki You are right... I am so silly, the $a, b, c, d$ should be integer values so it is possible there are no solutions. Hmmm they introduce modular arithmetic in the *next* chapter of the book but I will try...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki $3b - d - c = 0$ implies that $d+c$ must be $3b$, so a multiple of $3$, that is $d+c \equiv0\pmod 3$, which implies $c \equiv-d\pmod 3$. And then... for $3a-c+5d=1$ we can say that $c-5d=3a - 1$, so $c-5d \equiv-1\pmod 3$, which implies $c \equiv-1+5d\pmod 3$. Substituting the first equation for $c$ into the second, we get $-d \equiv-1+5d\pmod 3$, which implies $6d \equiv1\pmod 3$ which is a contradiction because $6d \equiv0\pmod 3$ ... is this right? If it is, then all that is said means that the assertion in OP is correct.

Comment: That looks like exactly the argument to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steven's comment is a good way to finish your solution. Here's an approach that will help with understanding the significance of your question: Multiply both sides by $1 - \sqrt{-5}$ to get
$$3x - (1 + \sqrt{-5})y = 1 \quad\implies\quad 3(1 - \sqrt{-5})x - 6y = 1 - \sqrt{-5}$$
The left-hand side can be factored as $3[(1 - \sqrt{-5})x - 2y]$. For any choice of "integers" $x$ and $y$, the quantity in brackets will be an "integer" $a + b\sqrt{-5}$, so the left-hand side is $3$ times an "integer", i.e. $3a + 3b\sqrt{-5}$. The right-hand side isn't of this form, so the equation has no solution.

These "integers" are the elements of the [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] = \{a + b\sqrt{-5} : a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. You can think of rings like $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ as analogous to the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ in that you can add/subtract/multiply two elements of the ring and get another element in the ring. But this question shows that [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) holds in $\mathbb{Z}$ but not in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. What this means is that you can't think about primes and factorization the same way. The essential difference between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is that [prime factorization is unique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain) in $\mathbb{Z}$ but not in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$; note that our solution above relied on the fact that $6$ can be factored two different ways: $$6 = 3 \cdot 2 = (1 + \sqrt{-5}) (1 - \sqrt{-5})$$ If you study algebraic number theory, you'll learn how to salvage this situation by defining primes in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ in [a slightly different way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal) so that prime factorization is unique. This allows us to do number theory in rings other than $\mathbb{Z}$, which is interesting in its own right and also helps us solve many classical problems over the integers, for example determining which prime numbers are expressible in the form $x^2 + ny^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\,\ w := 1+\sqrt{-5}\,\Rightarrow\, w\bar w = \color{#7cf}6\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{(w,3)(\bar w,3)} = \color{#7cf}3(\color{#7cf}2,w,\bar w,3) = \color{#c00}{(3)},\,$ but if $\,(3,w)=(1)\,$ then conjugating yields $\,(3,\bar w)=(1)\,$ so $\,(w,3)(\bar w,3) = \color{#c00}{(1)},\,$ contra above (more detail [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4340435/242)).

Similarly $\, \color{#0a0}{(w,2)(w,3)=(w)},\ \ \color{#90f}{(\bar w,2)(\bar w,3) = (\bar w)},\ \ (w,2)(\bar w,2) = (2)$

Using the above, the nonunique factorization $\, \color{#0a0}w\color{#90f}{\bar w} = 2\cdot\color{#c00}3\,$ of *numbers* can refined to a unique factorization of *ideals* using the below ideal analog of $\rm 4NT$ = [Four Number theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3835192/242)

$$  \overbrace{\color{#0a0}{(w,2)(w,3)}}^{\textstyle (\color{#0a0}w)}\overbrace{(\color{#90f}{\bar w,2)(\bar w,3)}}^{\textstyle (\color{#90f}{\bar w})} \,=\, \overbrace{(w,2)(\bar w,2)}^{\textstyle (\color{c00}2)}\overbrace{\color{#c00}{(w,3)(\bar w,3)}}^{\textstyle (\color{#c00}3)}$$

If those ideals were all principal $(x,y) = (z)$ then [we could read those ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3876422/242) as *number* gcds $\gcd(x,y)\approx z\,$ and then the above refinement is just the usual Four *Number* Theorem (which is true in any UFD or GCD domain, and yields uniqueness of factorizations into irreducibles).

So the significance of the nonprincipality of $(3,w)$  is that it implies that we have to pass from *number* gcds to *ideal* gcds in order to regain unique factorization.

Note: the gcd of ideals $I,J\,$ [is defined to be](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3405678/242) $\,I+J,\,$ so $\,(w,2) = (w)+(2)\,$ is the ideal gcd of $(w)$ and $(2),\,$ etc. The reason for this is that the ideal sum satisfies the universal property of the gcd in rings where contains = divides for ideals (e.g. PIDs and Dedekind domains), viz.

$$\begin{align} A\supseteq B,C &\iff A\supseteq B+C,\qquad\ \text{universal property of ideal sum}\\[.2em]
\rightsquigarrow\ \ A\ \mid\ B,C&\iff A\ \mid\  B+C,\qquad\ \text{when contains = divides}\\[.2em] 
A\ \mid\ B,C&\iff A\ \mid \gcd(B,C),\ \ \ \ \text{universal property of gcd}\end{align}$$

as explained in the prior linked answer.