# Let $a \in \Bbb{Z} _{\ge2}$ . Suppose that for all m,n $\in \Bbb{Z}^+$ if $a | mn$, then $a | m$ or $a | n$. Prove that a is a prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

to prove that a is a prime number, I need to show that a only has 2 divisors: 1 and itself. My approach to this question is to use the definition of divisibility and the hint in the question that since $a = k(mn)$, a will either be $a = i(m)$ or $a = j(n)$ (where i, j, k are constants) to show that either m and n either has to be a or 1. I'm not sure if the approach I'm taking is a correct/logical one.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/621913/242)

Comment: The question in the title is an assignment question I set for my students, word-by-word. The due date for my assignment is tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track, thinking about the divisors of $a$. Let me provide a proof by contradiction. Let $a\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 2}$ have the property given in the question, and assume $a$ is not prime. Well, then $a$ is composite, and so there exist integers $b,c$ greater than or equal to $2$ with $a=bc$. But then clearly, $a|a$ and so $a|bc$, but also clearly, $a\not|b$ and $a\not|c$. So something is wrong; $a$ can't be composite and it must be prime.

Comment: Does just simply giving a counter-example like $4|6*6$ but $4\not|6$ be incorrect?

Comment: @Leon It would be incorrect, yes. All your counter-example shows is that there is *some* composite number ($4$ in this case) that doesn't have the property. But it says nothing about any other composite numbers, and we need to prove that there are *no* composite numbers which have the desired property, i.e. the only numbers with the property we want are prime. :)