# Prove that $n$ is divisible by $5$ if and only if $n^2 $is divisible by $5$ and use it to prove that $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

Not sure about what cases to consider in part 1 of the proof and how to use it to prove the next part.

Comment: Mimic the [classic proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/621678/242)

Answer (score 4):

First part
Every natural number takes one of the following forms $(k\in\Bbb Z)$:
$$5k$$
$$5k+1$$
$$5k+2$$
$$5k+3$$
$$5k+4$$

You can then use the contrapositive to verify that statement, i.e. prove that:

$$5\nmid n \to 5\nmid n^2$$ by squaring each of the forms.

Second part: take $$\sqrt5=\frac ab\to 5=\frac{a^2}{b^2}\to 5b^2=a^2$$
which implies $a^2$ is a multiple of $5$ and hence $a$ is too (because of the first part you've already proven). You can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $p$ is a prime number and $p | ab$. Then $p|a$ or $p|b$.
Use this fact.  The other proposed solution also works.